# How do I get Reinforced.Typings to generate "export interface" or "export enum" as output, without wrapping it in a module?

Tags: c#, typescript, reinforced-typings

I'm using Reinforced.Typings to generate TypeScript models from my C# models. I want the models exported as the following, not wrapped in a module:

```
export interface IFoobar {
    someProperty: string;
    someOtherProperty: number;
}

export enum SomeEnum {
   someEnumValue = 0,
   someOtherEnumValue = 1
}
```

I am able to get it almost the way I want it by using the following configuration method:

```
public static void Configure(ConfigurationBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Global(config => config.CamelCaseForProperties()
                                   .AutoOptionalProperties());

    builder.ExportAsInterfaces(new [] { typeof(Foobar) },
                               config => config.WithPublicProperties()
                                               .AutoI()
                                               .DontIncludeToNamespace());

    builder.ExportAsEnums(new [] { typeof(SomeEnum) },
                          config => config.DontIncludeToNamespace());
}
```

This will create the following output, but the `export` keyword missing.

```
interface IFoobar {
    someProperty: string;
    someOtherProperty: number;
}

enum SomeEnum {
   someEnumValue = 0,
   someOtherEnumValue = 1
}
```

It is possible to achieve what I want? If possible I want to avoid attributes, and keep using the fluent API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try UseModules() in global config:

```
builder.Global(config => config.CamelCaseForProperties()
                               .AutoOptionalProperties()
                               .UseModules());
```

Comment: You're right, UseModules() does the trick. Why is it that UseModules() removes the module wrapper though?

Comment: My guess would be as good as yours on that matter. After inspecting UseModules(), you see summary as follows "Enables adaptation for TS modules system". Without UseModules() function, it just puts it in Module named after the backend namespace. Backend and frontend app architecture doesn't need to match. When you add export keyword in typescript, that class becomes visible across all TS modules (sort of like public keyword). Classes that you're generating from backend should only be used as data transfer objects, and therefore visible across all TS modules. Does that clarify it a bit?

Comment: you can also place `[assembly:TsGlobal(UseModules = true)]` at the root of any cs file in the assembly you are exporting from (easier for framework projects)